# Can't run Maya 2017 on Ubuntu 18.04 (error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4)

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, shared-library

I used [this instruction manual: "Install Autodesk Maya on Ubuntu 18.04"](https://linuxhint.com/install_autodesk_maya_ubuntu_1804/) to run Maya 2017 on Ubuntu 18.04:

When I tried to enter "/usr/autodesk/maya2017/bin/maya.bin", it displayed the message

```
/usr/autodesk/maya2017/bin/maya.bin: error while loading shared libraries: 
libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have repeated the instructions countless of times and made sure that the codes I entered are correct, but it always ended up with this message.

I'm not exactly good at programming and stuff, especially when it comes to Ubuntu, so it would really be a big help to me if anyone can help me with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to askubuntu.com! It seems, like `libcurl` (`/usr/lib/libcurl.so`) is not present on your system. Check if it is there and if not, try to install it. I tried locate package containing library you are missing with https://packages.ubuntu.com/ and it seems, that package which provides `libcurl` is `libcurl4` and [several others](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libcurl&searchon=names&suite=cosmic&section=all).